# Add Surface Information in 3d-analyst

Tags: arcmap, elevation, 3d-analyst

One of our guys is using the "Functional Surface->Add Surface Information" feature in 3D-analyst tool in ArcMap 10.1 to add elevation data to an XY list.  It's the only feature we're using from the 3D-analyst.  Our trial period has ended and we're trying to figure out if we need to buy the whole 3D-analyst tool for $2500 just for this feature, or if there's a cheaper way to do this task since we don't use anything else in 3D-analyst.  Since it's a pretty simple task, I might just develop a tool myself to do this using the USGS web service given the cost of 3D-analyst.

Is there a cheaper / easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should take a look at the extraction tool set in the spatial analysis toolbox .... if you have that extension :). The extract by points might be what your looking for. Failing that you could always try a cheeky work around by converting your surface data to polygons and doing a spatial join on the point data. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a web service for this, you may want to sign up for the beta program underway for their [World Elevation Service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_are_the_World_Elevation_services/009t00000244000000/).